# Switching of indices in Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry

Does $\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma$ equal $\Lambda^\mu_\sigma \Lambda^\nu_\kappa$ ? If so, why does it?
edit: this is the context:

$$\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}$$

So i'm wondering if it is allowed to swap the $\sigma$ and $\kappa$ in the lorentz transformations but not in $F$ (electromagnetic tensor)

Comment: Why do you think they are equal?

Comment: See edited question!

Comment: In $\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}$ and you sum over the repeated indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short version

> Does $\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma$ equal $\Lambda^\mu_\sigma \Lambda^\nu_\kappa$?

No.

> So I'm wondering if it is allowed to swap the $\sigma$ and $\kappa$ in the Lorentz transformations but not in $F$ (electromagnetic tensor)

Yes, as long as you flip the overall sign or also swap the two free indices:
\begin{equation}
  \Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}
  =
  -\Lambda^\mu_\sigma \Lambda^\nu_\kappa F^{\sigma \kappa}
  =
  \Lambda^\nu_\sigma \Lambda^\mu_\kappa F^{\sigma \kappa}.
\end{equation}

There are two easy ways to figure the first option out, and a different way to figure out the second.  You should probably make sure you understand all three if you intend to do much more tensor analysis.  It might be instructive to also think about swapping those indices on $\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma g^{\sigma \kappa}$.

## First derivation

The first way involves starting out by swapping the indices of $F^{\sigma \kappa}$, even though you don't want to end up with them swapped.  You know that $F$ is antisymmetric, so you get a relative minus sign when you swap its indices:
\begin{equation}
  \Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}
  =
  -\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\kappa \sigma}.
\end{equation}
But now, recognize that $\kappa$ and $\sigma$ are both [dummy indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables), meaning that you can rename them everywhere without any change in the result.  To make this really explicit, you could first change *every* instance of $\sigma$ to $\tau$, let's say; then every instance of $\kappa$ to $\sigma$; then every instance of $\tau$ to $\kappa$:
\begin{align}
  \Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}
  &=
  -\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\kappa \sigma} \\
  &=
  -\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\tau F^{\kappa \tau} \\
  &=
  -\Lambda^\mu_\sigma \Lambda^\nu_\tau F^{\sigma \tau} \\
  &=
  -\Lambda^\mu_\sigma \Lambda^\nu_\kappa F^{\sigma \kappa}.
\end{align}
That's the result you were looking for.

## Second derivation

The second way involves the contraction of symmetric and antisymmetric tensors.  The rule is that contracting a symmetric tensor with an antisymmetric tensor will always result in zero.  (This is a general result that you should prove for yourself by expanding each factor to explicitly show the symmetries.  It's frequently given as an early homework problem in relativity classes.)  For example, the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric, so $g_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} = 0$.

Now, take a look at the quantity $\Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma$.  You can use that general rule here on the lower indices; the upper indices just come along for the ride.  So the point is that only the antisymmetric part of the lower indices come into the result when you contract:
\begin{equation}
  \Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}
  =
  \Lambda^\mu_{[\kappa} \Lambda^\nu_{\sigma]} F^{\sigma \kappa}.
\end{equation}
(Note the antisymmetrization brackets on the lower indices.)  Now, you can use the fact that those two indices are antisymmetric:
\begin{equation}
  \Lambda^\mu_{[\kappa} \Lambda^\nu_{\sigma]}
  =
  -\Lambda^\mu_{[\sigma} \Lambda^\nu_{\kappa]}.
\end{equation}
So you have
\begin{align}
  \Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}
  &=
  \Lambda^\mu_{[\kappa} \Lambda^\nu_{\sigma]} F^{\sigma \kappa} \\
  &=
  -\Lambda^\mu_{[\sigma} \Lambda^\nu_{\kappa]} F^{\sigma \kappa}.
\end{align}
But again, only the antisymmetric part of the lower indices will come into it, so you can just get rid of the brackets once you're done using them:
\begin{align}
  \Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}
  &=
  \Lambda^\mu_{[\kappa} \Lambda^\nu_{\sigma]} F^{\sigma \kappa} \\
  &=
  -\Lambda^\mu_{[\sigma} \Lambda^\nu_{\kappa]} F^{\sigma \kappa} \\
  &=
  -\Lambda^\mu_{\sigma} \Lambda^\nu_{\kappa} F^{\sigma \kappa}.
\end{align}
Again, that's the result you were looking for.

## The other option

It's worthwhile remembering that the order of *tensors* in an expression doesn't actually matter — only the relation of indices to those tensors matters.  For example, if you have two tensors $A$ and $B$, the following is ***always*** true:
\begin{equation}
  A^\mu_\kappa B^\nu_\sigma = B^\nu_\sigma A^\mu_\kappa.
\end{equation}
It's true when there are different types of indices on the two tensors; it's true regardless of any other symmetries the tensors may have; it's ***always*** true.  [Ultimately, the reason is that $A$ and $B$ are maps into the real (or complex) numbers, and this expression means "multiply the resulting numbers", but the real (and complex) numbers commute, so it doesn't matter what order you multiply them in.]  This might be a little confusing and subtle, and I won't be surprised if I even get some people downvoting because they don't understand it.  But I bring it up because it gives you another way to rewrite your expression:
\begin{equation}
  \Lambda^\mu_\kappa \Lambda^\nu_\sigma F^{\sigma \kappa}
  =
  \Lambda^\nu_\sigma \Lambda^\mu_\kappa F^{\sigma \kappa}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Honestly, i am almost downvoting because of the last section. This is trivial, you are trying to mystify that 5*4=4*5. That is neither subtle nor a little confusing.

Comment: @lalala That's literally the opposite of what I was trying to do.  I specifically explained that it's as simple as 5*4=4*5 in order to demystify this.  And I speak from experience in teaching tensor manipulation to top-level students at top-level universities — they frequently get confused about that kind of manipulation.

Comment: @lalala aren't you being a little harsh there? Mike gave three different ways to understand the situation; you didn't quite like the last one -- so be it. Focus on the first and second ones. Someone else might find the third one illuminating, you never know. Unless there is something explicitly wrong there, I think a downvote is not the way to go here, right?

Comment: I think it's a bit distasteful to do the Reddit-style "I'll get downvoted for this but...". But I totally agree with the sentiment! Almost all my downvotes come from answers about the simplest things in Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: How do they get confused? $A_\mu^\kappa$ is a number. Maybe I am splitting hair, but it is not 'as simple as 5*4=4*5', it literally *is* 5*4=4*5.

Comment: @lalala If anything, you're not splitting enough hairs: $A^\kappa_\mu$ is absolutely not a number.  The expression above is *not* like 5*4=4*5; it's a *mapping into* something like that.  We're dealing with [abstract-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) here — not component values.  That distinction is what gives modern tensor notation its power.

Comment: In the expression $A_\kappa^\mu A_\sigma^\nu F^{\sigma \kappa}$ A_\kappa^\mu$ is a number for each value of kappa snd mu. The onlt obscurity is that we are using Einstein summation convention so the double sum symbol is missing. This expression is Ricci calculus. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus

Comment: Ok. I agree it could be confusing to understand in abstract tensor notation. So the implied mapping is alphabetical.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Lambda_\kappa^\mu\Lambda_\sigma^\nu F^{\sigma\kappa}=F^{'\nu\mu}$ while $\Lambda_\sigma^\mu\Lambda_\kappa^\nu F^{\sigma\kappa}=F^{'\mu\nu}=-F^{'\nu\mu}\ne F^{'\nu\mu}$, $\Lambda_\kappa^\mu\Lambda_\sigma^\nu\ne\Lambda_\sigma^\mu\Lambda_\kappa^\nu$.

Answer (score 0):

If you permute $\sigma \leftrightarrow \kappa$ in the expression involving $F$ the expression does not change because here the indices are summed over and so are dummy.

If, however, you wish to make only this permutation on the $\Lambda$ terms then in general the expression will not remain the same. In this case though you may use the antisymmetry of $F$ to show that the result is the same up to an overall minus, as the other answers demonstrate explicitly.

In the isolated expressions you mention initially, the indices are not dummy so they differ under the same permutation.

Comment: The question is about swapping the indices only on the $\Lambda $'s, and not on $F$.

Comment: Ah I misread, I will edit.